# Pallet extrinsic event not triggering when called through chain extension

Tags: ink, pallet, parachain, events, chain-extension

When I call the pallet extrinsic [bond_and_stake](https://github.com/ok-Alice/astar-frame/blob/main/frame/nomination-pool-staking/src/pallet/mod.rs#LL206C31-L206C31), the [Event](https://github.com/ok-Alice/astar-frame/blob/main/frame/nomination-pool-staking/src/pallet/mod.rs#L215) `BondAndStake` gets triggered. But when I call it through the [chain extension method](https://github.com/ok-Alice/astar-frame/blob/main/chain-extensions/nomination-pool-staking/src/lib.rs#L75-L101) from my [ink smart contract message](https://github.com/ok-Alice/liquid-staking/blob/main/contracts/issuer_staker/src/lib.rs#L100-L115), the event does not trigger, which leads me to believe that it didn't reach the pallet extrinsic function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was fixed by changing the parameter in the `build` method to `0x10001`. The indexes of the chain extension and function id were not correct.